# Symfony 5, How to display in a template, a variable where the current user is affiliated with a ManyToMany relations

Tags: php, database, symfony, templates, twig

I want that when my current user goes to the page, he can see what subject matter he is affiliated with a `ManyToMany` relation.

My entity Matter

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="matters")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="studentsMatters")
 */
private $student;
```

and my entity User

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $fullname;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Matter", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $matters;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Matter", mappedBy="student")
 */
private $studentsMatters;
```

and my controller to get the repository of Users and Matters

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="student_index", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function index(MatterRepository $matterRepository, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
{
    return $this->render('student/index.html.twig', [
        'matters' => $matterRepository->findAll(),
        'users' => $userRepository->findAll(),
    ]);
}
```

So in my template, I try several things like that

```
{% for user in users %}
{% for matter in matters %}
    {% if matter.student == app.user.fullname %}
        <div>{{ matter.name }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but it's doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens instead? Additionally, are you sure you are comparing properly? `matter.student` contains an object, while `app.user.fullname` might contain a string?

Comment: In my database, my current user is affiliated with a name
, so I want it to show me the names where the current user is affiliated, but with `matter.student == app.user.fullname`
he doesn't show me anything.

Comment: Well, obviously. Have you tried to debug this? What does `matter.student` contain (don't guess, don't argue, debug!), and what does `app.user.fullname` contain (also, don't guess, debug!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good, I found a solution to my problem!

First, I create a new entity which contains 2 OneToMany (one to put in relation my matters and the other, the users.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Matter", inversedBy="studentUsers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $studentMatter;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="studentUsers")
 */
private $user;
```

In my controller, I add these three lines to get send the current user.

```
$studentUser = new StudentUser();
$user = $this->getUser();
$studentUser->setUser($user);
```

Therefore, In my form, I just have to select the variable studentMatter that I want.

And to finish, I add as condition

```
{% if student_user.user.id == app.user.id %}
    <div>{{ student_user.studentMatter.name }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks to everyone who took their time trying to help me :)